# twisted python TCP4ServerEndpoint

Tags: twisted.internet

error no module TCP4.... found.
both on windows and ubuntu 10.04..
do i need to install anything new.
I tried to copy endpoints.py to a directory. but not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 includes Twisted 10.0.0, but the `twisted.internet.endpoints` module was introduced in Twisted 10.1.0. You can find more recent versions on the [twistedmatrix.com](http://twistedmatrix.com) or the [PYPI Twisted project page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted).

Once you have a more recent version installed, here is the import path to the TCP4ServerEndpoint class:

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
```